# A Scientifically Plausible Platform-Independent Information-Destroying Monster?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, military, information

I have dragons, unicorns, gryphons, whatnot. They live happily until the evil Monster Hunter Association shows up and starts killing them for sport. Well, it didn't happen yet, but I received intel that it definitely will. How do I end this problem forever?

Well, Terror Units, of course.

1. **Fear of the Dark (Nyctophobia) - Vashta Nerada:** shadow-dwelling swarms of barely-visible insects that can quickly strip a person of their flesh. Good for taking out larger units and area denial.
2. **Fear of Ghosts (Phasmophobia, not to be confused with [Phasmaphobia](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/true-villains/images/a/a3/Captain-phasma-armor.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170724181045)) - Ghosts:** It doesn't matter if you have the
   Fatalis armor, since a nanomachine ghost can just seep through the gaps and strangle (or drown?) you. They're dedicated assassination units that
   [stalk their target, entrap, and choke-a-b#tch them](https://youtu.be/BFZPAuQjbVY?t=420).

While these units are excellent at demolishing morale, their power lies in the element of surprise and novelty, which becomes diminished once people start to understand them. This is where the Third Antichrist comes in:

3. **Fear of the Unknown (Omniphobia) - Slenderman/[The Silence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=po8Jc7sLbP8)/Information-Destroying Monster/[SCP-055](http://www.scpwiki.com/scp-055)/Bill Clinton:** Those were only a handful of its supposed names, as any concrete or implied information on its exact nature have been destroyed.

Information-Destroying Monster (IDM) is my ultimate Trump (and Biden) card. It specializes in destroying, poisoning, and manipulating military intelligence on terror units or anything I deem necessary, regardless of its data storage, so:

- **Books**
- **Written documents**
- **Images**
- **HDD/SSD**
- **Sticky Notes**
- **Human Memory**
- **Holographic Storage**
- **Graffiti**
- **Comments under presidential debates**

are affected by it.

While I'm sure the ideal monster is not achievable, here are its two main metrics. One is for precision (how hard it is to tell the document has been faked) and speed:

### Speed:

**Level 1 - Stored documents:** One day, general Ripper wakes up to find a report on his computer about a Declaration of War by *The Society of Oppressed Gamers* who have over 9000 trained riflemen that aren't afraid of death and twice as many wooden crosses for burning journalists and heretics, according to the report.

**Level 2 - Active communications:**

Then, a by-the-book lieutenant, known for his stoicism, says, *"Don't worry, general they're still in heat which makes them more aggressive, but it quickly goes away"*.

The general is like, *"Quit joking, we might have a serious data loss here!"* With that, he deletes about 420 confidential documents that have become "The cake is a lie", repeated over their entire length.

*"I didn't say anything, general".*

*"I didn't say anything either".*

---

With some added speed, even Level 1 would be pretty good, even with limited memory manipulation. Think about it. **These are things a Level 1 should be capable of**:

- Missing intel?
- Having to allocate resources to educating soldiers about memes?
- The several thousand messages, mailed to The Human Resources Department;
  demanding to "reinstate Monica Cellio" and ban soylent green, are the only messages sent to that department?
- "[General Ripper](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GeneralRipper) was an impostor, two impostors remaining"
- Sublime [TvTropes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) links appearing in documents?
- Tank Operating Manuals that mislead people, tell them to "git gud", or are just a faithful copy of [Tigerfibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigerfibel)?

Nuking training and resource allocation will turn the atmosphere of any war room from Dr.Strangelove to Der Untergang, especially since they accidentally ordered "senpai" instead of "pie".

(*With true memory manipulation, we can push the [despair envelope](https://youtu.be/chFcXCCi17E?t=13) further:*)

That is if they don't go broke over the cost of anti-depressants, as it is now a very real possibility that originally, monster hunters outnumbered The Foundation, and that the dust in the living quarters is YOUR DEAD COMRADES' ASHES.

**That being said, I'm having trouble with how the Level 1 creature could work. It has to remain undetected (at least until it can erase its traces), be able to forge documents, access and corrupt any data storage, and do all of it relatively fast, though not as fast that it could attack active communication.**

**So, how could my IDM work?**

Comment: I remember writing this question, but I don't remember writing it this way. Wait, what day is today?

Comment: For manipulating human minds/electronic storage, manipulation of strong EM fields springs to mind, but idk how to use that to change physical documents.

Comment: You can't make one "science-based" thing destroy sticky-notes, human memory, books, and hard disks, without destroying all the underlying media. That is, something like nuking the entire planet. Voting to close.

Comment: Can you make the question clearer with less dialogues and "stream of conscious" flavor?

Answer (score 1):

#### Tiny nanorobots

This is the only thing that can disconnect human neurons, flatten holographic storage, flip the bits in flash memory, blank sticky notes, and strip graffiti from a wall, etc. without destroying the container (human brain, CD, etc)

This is computationally very complex, your basically needing to map the world down to the atom as your bots move around in order to do this. But with some filtering of where to look for data, a massive supercomputer processing data streamed to/from the nanobots and some plausible handwaving of computation advances and nanobot tech, this is just within the realm of possibility.

Comment: What if the nanites were to posess someone to do most of the job  for them? Like a clumsy janitor in a server room?

Answer (score 0):

**Is time travel allowed? If not, can the monster be a bit precognitive?**

First, most of the monster is nothing special. It only needs:

- High dexterity and high kinaesthetic senses along fingers to forge handwriting
- A method of destroying ink (secretes chemicals?) and printing ink (inbuilt printer?)
- Some sort of computer interface. Could even just be keyboard and fingers, along with some hacking skill
- A meme database (offline reddit or something would work)
- High-bandwidth information gathering and synthesis system (able to incorporate data, gps feeds, camera views, included radar, echolocation, etc into a coherent panoptical vision)

The real keystone to the monster's functioning is either time-travel or some sort of precognitive ability (I'm going to refer to precognition or time time travel simply as "Key" for simplicity). With the Key it can take all the time it needs to change the information before it's accessed and can easily dodge any observation. For example:

- Missing intel: Using the Key, the monster determines when the intel will be unguarded or find the slightest unobserved gap in the intel's chain of custody. Then it goes there and steals or destroys it. The older/less relevant intel is, the less it's under observation, and the easier it is to find a time window or precognitive path leading to the intel without being observed or recorded.
- Falsified intel: similarly to how the monster would steal intel, it creates memes using its meme database and plants them instead.

Now, let's take apart the Key and it's implications:

**Time travel:** Time travel is an ugly thing and very difficult to write without violently splattering plot holes and causality paradoxes all over your neatly arranged space-time continuum. Nevertheless, it *is* possible. When your general decides to crack open his personal copy of *The Art of War* or whatever generals read, he discovers that the text was changed. The monster did this by:

1. Observing that the general cracked open his book or learning after the fact that he did
2. Jumping backwards in time and covertly observing the book until it was alone and enough time was there to change it
3. Strip the words off the pages with secreted chemicals and print new ones from the meme-database
4. Put the book back where the monster found it

The advantage of the time-traveling monster is that you only need one. At any one point in time, there are probably dozens or hundreds simultaneous incarnations of this monster performing nefarious deeds of sabotage. Furthermore, if the monster was able to collaborate with itself, it would be more effective at planning windows where the data is unprotected.

Interestingly, an organization seeking to combat this monster would have an interesting fight ahead of them. If they manage to kill one incarnation of the monster, but that specific one was late in it's own timeline, only a small fraction of data would be un-re-written. They'd need to kill the youngest, but not necessarily earliest, version of the monster to undo all the data corruption.

**Precognition:** This is probably more "realistic" than time travel as it's possible computationally, at least to a certain degree. Using an ultra-uber-supercomputational system and inputting all the data, the monster would be able to map out the near future to a high degree of probability and act on those results. For example:

1. The Key calculates with >98% certainty that the general will go to the upper floor officer's bathroom at 15:32 in 13 hours. This is calculated by taking into account the habits of all the base personnel, their schedules, what food he will likely eat due to his personal taste, the health of his gastrointestinal system from the doctor's reports, etc. Furthermore, the Key calculates it highly likely that while the general is sitting on his porcelain throne, he'll crack open his copy of *The Art of War* to some random pages in the middle because he's bored. It is decided to edit this book.
2. Similarly to how the Key determined when the general would next open his book, it uses the computational power of the precognitive engine to determine an unobstructed and unobserved path to the book and back using guard schedules, maintenance plans, prior observations, etc.
3. When the time is right, the monster sneaks in, changes the book, and sneaks out.

Likely, even with all the computational power and extreme observation capabilities, it's unlikely that the micro-level future can be predicted to high accuracy at long temporal ranges; this span can be on the order of hours or days up to maybe weeks for "big picture" stuff. Also, unlike the time-travel variant, many monsters are required because they're comparatively slower and you might need to include some stealth capabilities like invisibility to make it easier on the monster.

The perfect way to combat this monster would be to tie the actions of people and systems to unpredictable random number generators that even the supercomputer can't get a handle on. For example, the military might cotton on to the fact that if they reduce data-monster interventions if they control their guard rotations by quantum-number-generator.